# Basic Template for custom page

Tags: ee2

I would like the ability to set up individual pages for announcements. These pages would be read by employees only and they would have a specific url to to see these pages.   Example: "We are closed today due to weather"

Is there a plugin for this or do we need to build them under "Basic Templates?"

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [**Pages Module**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/) for this. It will allow your users to easily create announcement pages with custom URLs and will keep your template set-up very minimal.

1. Create a re-usable "announcements" template to serve these entries (call it say, `pages.group/_announcements.html`).
2. Create an "Announcments" Channel. In the Pages module configuration set the default template for this channel to be the new template you created for these entries.
3. Finally, when publishing an entry in this Channel just be sure you give it a Pages URI. The Pages URI is a custom URL where your entry can be viewed (it can be anything you like).

On the other hand...

If having custom URLs for your announcements is not important, or you think you'll never need to offer the user the ability to create other types of one-off "pages" on the site, then you would be fine to forgo the Pages module and just create a template to serve content from this Channel (eg `announcements.group/index.html`). This would mean all your announcement page URLs would begin with the template group name and be very systematic, rather than custom. But that's not necessarily a bad thing.